# How to fix encoding problems with Puppet

Tags: ruby, encoding, puppet

I am in the file encoding hell with Puppet.
Even the simplest try does not work:

```
hiera-data/test.yaml:
---
test: Äñö

init.pp:
  $test = hiera('test')
  file { "/root/encoding.txt":
    ensure  => file,
    content => $test
  }
```

On the Puppet server everything looks fine:

```
puppet:~ # file -i /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera-data/env/test.yaml
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera-data/env/test.yaml: text/plain charset=utf-8
puppet:~ # cat /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera-data/env/test.yaml
---
test: Äñö
puppet:~ # locale
LANG=POSIX
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

On the puppet agent:

```
puppet-test:~ # locale
LANG=POSIX
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

After running:

```
puppet-test:~ # file -i encoding.txt
encoding.txt: text/plain charset=utf-8
```

but

[image: cat encoding.txt]

Here is the HEX data asked for:

```
0000000: efbf bdef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd efbf bdef  ................
0000010: bfbd 0a                                  ...
```

Running hiera directly does not provide any further insight. In special, I can only try it on the server, since the agent does not have the sources.
[image]

My environment is quite outdated, but I am not allowed to use any newer version, at least not yet, without any GOOD reason:

- SuSE Enterprise Linux 11 Service Pack 3
- Puppet Enterprise 3.8.6
- pe-ruby-1.9.3.551-9.pe.sles11

I would appreciate any insight to this problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not your terminal?  Open `encoding.txt` in a hex editor (or in a text editor with a binary / hex mode) and check whether the file contains the correct bytes.  In particular, the UTF-8 encoding for the string you present would consist of these six bytes: `c3 84 c3 b1 c3 b6`.  If it contains something different, then please add that to your question.

Comment: i updated the question with the missing info, Thanks @JohnBollinger

Comment: After a second look at this, this does not seem like a puppet problem. This seems like a system env problem.

Comment: @MattSchuchard: could be, but what could i check to get further?

Comment: What do you get if you use hiera from the command line? e.g.:
`
# hiera -d test > test-encoding.txt
`
(you may have to use -c <config> to find the right files)

Comment: Question updated, thanks @PeterFaller, but no new insight...

Comment: What's the locale on the server ? The bytes in `encoding.txt` don't seem to make any sense. Here's how to recreate this file for debugging: `File.open('encoding.txt','w') { |f| f.write ["efbfbdefbfbdefbfbdefbfbdefbfbdefbfbd0a"].pack('H*') }`

Answer (score 0):

Having `LANG=POSIX` can definitely make things screwy.  `LANG` is what determines the encoding that the console displays.  It is usually desirable to have `LANG` and `LC_TYPE` matching.

See: "[Explain the effects of export LANG, LC_CTYPE, LC_ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479607/explain-the-effects-of-export-lang-lc-ctype-lc-all)".

And for more info on `LANG=POSIX` see [POSIX Locale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/locale.html#tag_005_002).

Also, on an unrelated note, Puppet 3.8 definitely has defects around properly displaying and/or persisting Unicode characters.  A lot of work has been done in the more recent Puppet builds to completely internationalize and localize Puppet.

Comment: Hi @Sam, sorry but your answer, nor the links, give me any glue what to try next... anyhow, i get the same results on a node using `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8`. But still many thanks for answering...