# Don't ignore whitespaces when using wscanf for UTF-8

Tags: c, wchar-t, specifier

I am trying to read wide charaters into an array of `wchar_t` from stdin. However, the negated scanset specifier (`[^characters]`) for `ls` does not work preperly as  expected.

The goal is that I want every whitespace read into `str` instead of being ignored. Hence, `[^\n]` is what I've tried, but with no luck, the result is frustrating and keeps printing garbled text to stdout.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    wchar_t str[8];

    if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8") == NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to set locale LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // correct (but not what I want)
    // whitespaces and EOLs are ignored
    // while (wscanf(L"%7ls", str) != EOF)  {
    //     wprintf(L"%ls", str);
    // }

    // incorrect
    // whitespaces (except EOLs) are properly read into str (what I want)
    // input: 不要忽略白空格 (for instance)
    // output: endless loop (garbled text)
    while (wscanf(L"%7[^\n]ls", str) != EOF)  {
        if (ferror(stdin) && errno == EILSEQ)  {
            fprintf(stderr, "Encountered an invalid wide character.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        wprintf(L"%ls", str);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `ls` doing in `"%7[^\n]ls"`?  Try `while (wscanf(L"%7[^\n]", str) == 1)`  and then you need some code to consume the `'\n'`.

Comment: @chux That all format specifiers have the same meaning as in scanf; therefore, %lc shall be used to read a wide character (and not %c), as well as %ls shall be used for wide strings (and not %s). Source: [C++ Ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wscanf/)

Comment: The reference does not suggest appending `ls` after `"%[something]"`  `"%[...]"` and `"%s"` are different specifiers.

Comment: @chux `[^characters]` is called a specifier, and according to that webpage, appending `[^\n]` before `ls` shall have the same meaning as in `scanf`. `scanf("%[^\n]s", str);` is a well-known solution to cope with reserving whitespaces, so `wscanf` should also work as expected.

Comment: Try `while (wscanf(L"%7[^\n]", str) != EOF)  { wscanf(L"%*1[\n]"); if (ferror(stdin)  ...`

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s", str);` is a well known and _incorrect_ solution.  The `s` is not needed, buffer over-run and `\n` is never consumed, which leads to problems here.

Comment: @chux That doesn't work. `scanf("%*[^\n]s", len - 1, str);` is better to avoid memory corruption. You can specify the maximum length that `scanf` is able to read.

Comment: `scanf("%*[^\n]s", len - 1, str);` confuses the `printf` and `scanf` specifiers.  With `scanf()` , `*` directs to not save.  The C spec calls it the "assignment-suppressing character"

Comment: @chux The problem is that `wscanf` is one of the proper way to read wide characters. `fread` is safer, but I don't want to cope with the unicode format. Do you have any proper way to read wide characters and also not ignore whitespaces?

Comment: Yes [this is close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45944875/dont-ignore-whitespaces-when-using-wscanf-for-utf-8?noredirect=1#comment78848824_45944875) as long as no lines are blank.  Or better, use `fgetws()`.

Comment: @chux The [result](http://imgur.com/a/jRG1g) is garbled after applying your suggestions even if no lines are blank.

Comment: @chux Great. `fgetws` works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KevinDong - do notice that `fgetws` might **not** use UTF-8 (on linux it often does use UTF-8, see the [`LC_CTYPE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479607/explain-the-effects-of-export-lang-lc-ctype-lc-all) environment variable). On the other hand, UTF-8 characters use variable length (between 1 and 4 bytes) and white space is encoded the same as ASCII (1 byte, same ASCII value), so you should be able to safely ignore encoding when processing for white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Don't ignore whitespaces ...
>   ... trying to read wide characters into an array of wchar_t

To read a line of *text* (all characters, and white-spaces up to `'\n'`) into a wide character *string*, use `fgetws()`;

```
#define STR_SIZE 8
wchar_t str[STR_SIZE];

while (fgetws(str, STR_SIZE, str)) {
  // lop off the potential \n if desired
  size_t len = wcslen(str);
  if (len > 0 && str[len-1] == L'\n') {
    str[--len] = L'\0';
  }
  ...
}
```